# How can I generate a search results page from a list of contact IDs, programatically?

Tags: search

I have an extension that lets people filter contacts in various ways. I'd like them to be able to click to show these contacts in a standard Civi results page - with the action box at the top etc. So that they can manipulate them in the normal ways, by adding to groups and such.

Is there a recommended way to do this, programatically?

Comment: we have done some work to enable lots of elements be filtered via the url so menu links can be set up - if that sounds useful i will dig out the documentation

Answer (score 2):

We have done work that is hopefully heading to Civi core which makes the following possible:

Below is the table of field name vs params that can be used in the URL to force the search results.

**Contribution Tokens**

Field Name > > Param in URL

contribution_page_id > > pid

financial_type_id > > fid

contribution_status_id > > status

is_pay_later > > pay_later

receive_date_from > > (receive_date)    start

receive_date_to > > (receive_date)  end

Eg of complete search URL -

"civicrm/contribute/search?reset=1&force=1&status=1&fid=2&pay_later=1&start=20181206&end=20181210"

**Membership Tokens**

Field Name > > Param in URL

membership_type_id > > type

membership_status_id > > status

start_date > > start & start_high

end_date > > end & end_high

Eg of complete search URL -

"civicrm/member/search?reset=1&force=1&type=1&status=1&start=20181002&start_high=20181004&end=20181103&end_high=20181109"

**Participant Tokens**

Field Name > > Param in URL

event_id > > event

status_id > > status

role_id > > role

is_pay_later > > pay_later

register_date_from > > register_start

register_date_to > > register_end

Eg of complete search URL -

"civicrm/event/search?reset=1&force=1&event=1&status=2&role=3&pay_later=1&register_start=20181210&register_end=20181214"

**Activity Tokens**

Field Name  Param in URL

activity-type id > > type

activity_status > > status

has a follow-up activity > > hasFollowUp

is a follow-up acivity > > isFollowUp

start date > > dateLow

end date > > dateHigh

Eg of complete search URL -

civicrm/activity/search?reset=1&force=1&status=1&hasFollowUp=1&isFollowUp=1&dateLow=20181210&dateHigh=20181212&type=3

Here is the link to the gitlab ticket https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/252

Answer (score 1):

If you rejig your extension so that your filtering is done via "custom search" then you automatically get that. See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-search

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that's not quite how my extension works - there's a lot of API work, which custom searches don't like very much. Is it possible to fire a list of contact IDs at a page?

Comment: I haven't tested this but I suppose you could write a separate very simple custom search which takes as input a comma-separated list of ids, then do a redirect to it from your existing extension with force=1, e.g. CRM_Utils_System::redirect( CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/contact/search/custom', "reset=1&force=1&csid={$myCustomSearchId}&inputField={$csvListOfIds}")); where inputField is whatever you call the form field that takes the list of ids in the custom search. You might not even need a field just retrieve directly from the url. It's clunky - maybe somebody else has better.

Comment: You may be able to use the search builder to post a comma separated list of IDs when using the search criteria "contact id IN".

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the api in your extension to create a group out of the results, then redirect to the group's group page, which has the same actions dropdown that search results does.

You might end up with a lot of stale groups lying around, but you could have a cron script delete the groups daily or something like that.